# Incrementing with a fraction based on user input

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I'm having trouble i need to take a user input and increment it by 1/10 starting at 0 so if the user enters a 5.2 i need to to go through 0.1 0.2 0.3 etc display each and stop at 5.2 until the method is called again and a new input is entered here is what i have but it just runs through up until 10 i understand why it does this just not enough to be able to fix this any help would be appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SpeedChange {


    public double startSpeed;
    public double newSpeed;

    public void changeUserSpeed(){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("How fast would you like to go between 1-10 mph?");
        double newSpeed = sc.nextDouble();
        for(newSpeed = sc.nextDouble(); newSpeed <= 10.00; newSpeed+=.1 ){
           System.out.println(newSpeed); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried?

Comment: You might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour (and also won a badge by doing so!)

Comment: i tried the one i posted as well as rather than a for loop using if(newSpeed <10){ System.out.println("Your going: " + newSpeed + "mph") but that simply displayed the change not all the increments inbetween

Comment: Thanks @Eypros---It helped me earning that bronze badge 'Informed`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your loop content.Since your newSpeed has been specified by the user,you don't need to alter it.You simply need to create a new double variable,say `Speed`,which will increment in the limit of 0.1 at each iteration and keep running until your `Speed` equals `newSpeed`.

```
for(double Speed=0;Speed<=newSpeed;Speed+=0.1 ){
       System.out.println(Speed); }
```

I hope this clears and solves your doubt!

Comment: thank you this did work but im displaying a lot of extra decimals  .00.10.20.300000000000000040.40.50.60.70.79999999999999990.899999999   and so forth how could i cut down the display to just 3 decimal points?

Comment: assuming i just want to display the first 2-3 so it'd be .10 .20 .30 .40 .50 .60 after .70 its .79999999999990 and there's many like that through the output

Comment: You can use `double Speed = 0.3000000000000;
DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
double threeDecimal =  Double.valueOf(newFormat.format(d));`
I hope it helps,please mark the answer as accepted!

Comment: thank you that helped immensely have been working through this for a few hours now

Answer (score -2):

Your code should instead be

```
    for(double speed=0; speed <= newSpeed; speed+=.1 ){
       System.out.println(speed); 
    }
```

P.S: double/float is not suitable for this kind of use. Use BigDecimal class to do this.

For details, see http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/02/java-mistake-1-using-float-and-double.html?m=1

Comment: Why exactly is float insufficient for this? Please back that claim up with facts.

Comment: The linked article is about monetary or financial computations, presumably in a context where data safety is extremely important. I fail to see how this is in any way relevant to the question.